# Huge fort.# files when running gfortran

Tags: macos, matlab, fortran, mex, gfortran

I am using gfortran for an application and running the Fortran through a Matlab `mex` file.  I have noticed that in the current directory when I run the Fortran file, on my mac, it creates a `fort.9` or `fort.16` file, where the 9 or 16 are some arbitrary number. Recently, I have noticed that these `fort.` files can be GBs big!  Generally they are quite small, like a few kBs.  I was just wondering what purpose these files have?  And second, is there some error I have in my code that is causing them to be so large?  I just find it to be very suspicious that they are so large.

I am running  GNU Fortran (GCC) 5.0.0 20140824 (experimental) from http://hpc.sourceforge.net/ and my version of mac is OSX 10.8.5.

Comment: Such a file may be the result of the program writing to unit `9` (or `16` or whatever `#` is) without that unit having previously been connected to a named file. A scan through your code will tell you if this is an issue for you.

Comment: Another possible reason for the creation of such files is a program attempting to write to the console when it (the program) is running without a console attached.  I imagine it's possible that your mex file runs without a console and that, on occurrence of some error you wot not  of, it writes GBs of error messages and diagnostics.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Fortran, contrary to most other languages, one can write to a unit (~=file object, or file descriptor in some other languages) without first opening it (connecting the unit to a file). In that case, gfortran will implicitly create a file in the current working directory called 'fort.N', where N is the unit number (other compilers may do something else, but generally do something similar).

So to answer your question, in your code you're writing stuff to those units. Why you're doing that I cannot obviously say without looking at the code in question.

Comment: you're spot on.  I looked at the files and realized that they are simply some diagnostic print statements I have in the fortran.  Basically I continually add to them, which drives the size up.  So I will edit my code to not have those files get out of control.  I should have done some more work before posting, but I thought the files were binary for some reason.  Thanks!

Comment: This isn't quite true (being pedantic). The unit must be connected to a file with write action allowed before one can write to that unit. It's just that units can be preconnected and then the connected file can be created by a write statement.