# Fortran temporary files

Tags: fortran

I've noticed that when my fortran code is running, the executable generates several temporary files with the name patter `fort*` where `*` is a 6 digit alpha numeric. The number of files generated corresponds to the number of threads the program is running on. The files are cleared once the program exits.

What are these files? And what is stored in them?

Edits: The program has no commands that generate these files.

Comment: Those files generated by the program. You need to examine the source code or ask the author.

Comment: These files are often generated when a write statement uses a unit#  that either does not have an open statement or has an open statement that failed. The alpha numeric part sometimes corresponds to the unit#. In  a threaded program without sufficient measures, you probably have a contention issue with multiple threads trying to write the same file.

Comment: @VladimirF they are not specifically generated by the authors. That is confirmed. I hope that is not the only reason you close the question.

Comment: @newkid I personally didn't actually close it. But I can assure you that Fortran will NOT create any files just for fun. It only does what the programmer tells it to do. There must be a `write` statement that creates them. They just won't appear out of thin air. So without seeing those `write` statements we really cannot tell you what is in those files. without seeing your code we cannot really help you or the code's author. See [mcve].

Comment: The only thing that we can say is that if you do `write(11,*) "foo"` without opening unit 11 a file `fort.11` containing 'foo" will appear. We certainly cannot tell you what are *your* files and what is stored in your files. You must examine and test your code. Or show a [mcve] and ask for it to be explained.

Comment: As this looks a genuin question I would be interested to see someone posting an answer and turn it into a wiki. End of Review.

Comment: @ZF007 The question asks to explain the behavior of code that it does not show.

Comment: We also have this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61617148/why-does-fortran-write-to-fort-x

Comment: @VladimirF ... OP stated its not behavior that comes from the code of the author. The answer is simultaneously `true` and `false`; and it depends on the view towards the issue. For answering the question its totally irrelevant to show code of the author here because the question is fundamental from origin; even though OP is not realizing that. To be frank you should know this as well as you're teaching Fortran. Once the question is open again I'll post an answer. Its to elaborated for comments only.

Comment: @ZF007 We already have a general explanation at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27669476/huge-fort-files-when-running-gfortran  Also, I teach Fortran, not FORTRAN.

Comment: The comment at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27670027/8928024) answer suffices.